# Using OpenStreetMap in my c++ program

Tags: c++, windows, gps, openstreetmap

I have a gpx file. I need a open source library that i can give it the gpx file and that it will present the route on a map. Does anyone know such a thing?

I'm writing in c++ on windows xp.

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists a bunch of Frameworks to map the OSM APIs to different languages.

Please check out this wiki-page from OSM: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop/Frameworks

I think what you search for can be found under [Widgets](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop/Frameworks#Widgets) like for example "COSMCtrl 1.1.3"